# in perl how to write to caller's variable without using XS?

Tags: perl, mocking, mod-perl2

I'm writing unit tests around some old code, and find the need to write a mock around Apache2::Request's `read()` method

```
my $r = Apache2::Request->new(...);

$r->read(my $buf, $len);
```

Is there a way to write a function in Perl to populate `$buf`? I'm pretty sure the only way to do that is from XS code with a **, but I thought I'd at least ask first.

Using Apache2::Request directly leads to this, hence my desire to mock it.

```
perl: symbol lookup error: .../APR/Request/Apache2/Apache2.so: 
undefined symbol: modperl_xs_sv2request_rec
```

Comment: So you want to mock the `read`, is that correct?

Comment: Perl always passes by reference, so all you have to do is modify `$_[1]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a Perl subroutine or method, parameters are passed via the `@_` array.  Elements in this array are *aliases* for the variables in the calling sub.

The common way of unpacking `@_` is by making a copy like this:

```
my($self, $buf, $len) = @_;
```

So assigning to `$buf` in this case won't work because you've only modified your copy of the variable.  But if you directly modify the value in `@_` then that will affect the caller's variable:

```
$_[1] = 'some data';
```

Comment: Haha, I really out-thought myself there. Thanks!